# Error:(22, 13) Failed To Resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0

Tags: android-studio

Just started learning Android Studio. I am on Android Studio 2.3.3.

Trying to work on a mapActivity and whenever project is synced, I get this error.

[image: Error:(22, 13) Failed To Resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0]

And when I click on "Install Repository and sync project", It does nothing.

Not sure how to get it working.

It's my build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And Top-level build file is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: check your sdk manager you might not have this installed, or just change the version to 11.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem where I had a + at the end of the compile library version. I removed the + and simply used 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
fixed it for me, I wonder if you can try a different version and see if that works.